# Can anyone explain to me why $(34)(123) = (124)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$$\begin{align}
(34)H&=  \{(34)(1),(34)(123),(34)(132)\}\\
& = \{(34),(124),(1432)\}.
\end{align} $$

Can anyone explain to me why $(34)(123) = (124)$?

I don't understand coset multiplying can you help me with this

Comment: I think its a Typo! Since $(34)$ is an odd permutation and $(123)$ is an even permuatation, so the product $(34)(123)$ is must be an odd permuatation. However $(124)$ is even!

Answer (score 3):

Its depends of the composition is from right to left or the opposite. If you consider from right to left, so $$1 \mapsto 2 \mapsto 2, \qquad 2 \mapsto 3 \mapsto 4, \qquad 4 \mapsto 4 \mapsto 3, \quad \mbox{and} \quad 3 \mapsto 1 \mapsto 1.$$ Hence $(34)(123) = (1243)$. Similiarly, from left to right, we have $(34)(123)=(1234).$ In both cases, $(34)(123) \neq (124)$. Comparing with $(34)(132)=(1432)$, the result was to be $(34)(123) = (1243)$. There must have been just one typo.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sigma=(123)$, $\tau=(34)$, and we compose right-to-left (as is consistent with your other compositions), then

$$\begin{align}
1 &\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto} 2 \stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto}2, \\
2&\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto} 3 \stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto} 4, \\
4 &\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto} 4 \stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto} 3, \\
3 &\stackrel{\sigma}{\mapsto} 1 \stackrel{\tau}{\mapsto} 1,
\end{align}$$

so $\tau\sigma=(34)(123)=(1243)$.